# test cases for Reverse words in a given string

Tags: c++, string, reverse

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void reverse(string &a,int i,int j)
{
char temp;
//j=j-1;
while(i<j)
{
    temp=a[i];
    a[i]=a[j];
    a[j]=temp;
    i++;
    j--;
}

}
void reversewords(string &a)
{
string b=a,c;
int i=-1,j=0;
while(j<a.length())
{
    if(i==-1 && a[j]!=' ' )
    {

        i=j;
    }
    if(a[i] && (a[j+1]==' ' || a[j+1]=='\0'))
    {

        reverse(a,i,j);
        i=-1;
    }
    j++;
}
reverse(a,0,a.length()-1);
//cout<<i<<" "<<j;
}
int main()
{
string a;
getline(cin,a);
reversewords(a);
cout<<a;
}
```

Reverse the ordering of words in a string.i implemented the above code by seeing one of the question in stack overflow

now what my question is i failing in some of he test cases

I got some of the test cases correct which are given below

1) An empty string.

2) String with only one space. Ex: " ".

3) String with multiple spaces in between words.

4) String with spaces at the starting. Single and multiple.

5) String with spaces at the end. Single and multiple.

6) String with only uppercase and only lowercase letters

7) String with alphanumeric.

8) Include special characters in step 7.

9) Strings which are palindromes.

10) String with only one character.

12) String with combinations of uppercase and lowercase letters.

13) String with only special characters.

cases where i am failing is

1. if a string contains more than two spaces in it

when there two spaces it is printing some extra characters.what changes i must do inorder to get correct output for more than two space also

Comment: +1 for test cases. Can you give an example of input, expected output, and actual output that is failing the test.

Comment: Test case 2) fails for me. Also you forgot to add `#include <string>` to that code, it does not compile otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you just add a flag after the character is ' ' so that your code wont think it's a new word then your problem should be solved. I guess the question is whether you want to print the empty space in your output.